# Are the effects granted by the TI Compendium permanent?

Tags: dota-2

All's in the title. The question encompasses effects such as "Custom Dagon/Eul's Scepter/Bottle/Fountain Effect" acquired through the compendium achievements and whether they alter these factors permanently or until a certain date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if they follow the usual system, any custom effects and animations that are not tied into equippable cosmetic items or gems will expire shortly after the International tournament has completed.